# Resizing of an AutoScroll Panel affects scrolled position

Tags: winforms, autoscroll

When I resize the following form with the right resize handle, the contained TableLayoutPanel gets decorated with scroll bars (as intended, `panel1.AutoScroll = true`) for smaller form sizes, but the TableLayoutPanel also gets displaced from its original position. See images below: after resizing the form with right resize handle only, the second one has its scroll bars not leftmost and the left border of the content is cut off.

It seems somehow that this behavior is tied to the existence of the nested RadioButtons because if I remove them (or replace them by another TextBox for example), the "normal" behavior is restored (TableLayoutPanel stays in place during resize).

What properties do I have to set in order to keep the content always stationary relative to the (top)left borders?

[image]

[image]

BTW: When I replace the panel1 by a TabControl + one TabPage, the "normal" behavior is also restored.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of Form3.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        const int textBoxNameWidth = 500;

        TableLayoutPanel testControl1;
        Panel panel1;
        TextBox textBoxName;
        RadioButton radioButtonNo;
        RadioButton radioButtonYes;
        TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanelDecision;

        public Form3()
        {
            testControl1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
            panel1 = new Panel();
            textBoxName = new TextBox();
            radioButtonNo = new RadioButton();
            radioButtonYes = new RadioButton();
            tableLayoutPanelDecision = new TableLayoutPanel();

            testControl1.AutoSize = true;
            testControl1.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            testControl1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            testControl1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            testControl1.ColumnCount = 2;
            testControl1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            testControl1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            testControl1.RowCount = 2;
            testControl1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            testControl1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            testControl1.Controls.Add(textBoxName, 1, 0);
            testControl1.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanelDecision, 1, 1);

            textBoxName.Text = "New Boolean";
            textBoxName.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            textBoxName.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
            textBoxName.TabStop = false;
            textBoxName.Width = textBoxNameWidth;

            tableLayoutPanelDecision.AutoSize = true;
            tableLayoutPanelDecision.ColumnCount = 2;
            tableLayoutPanelDecision.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50f));
            tableLayoutPanelDecision.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50f));
            tableLayoutPanelDecision.RowCount = 1;
            tableLayoutPanelDecision.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanelDecision.Controls.Add(radioButtonYes, 0, 0);
            tableLayoutPanelDecision.Controls.Add(radioButtonNo, 1, 0);
            tableLayoutPanelDecision.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            radioButtonNo.Checked = true;
            radioButtonNo.AutoSize = true;
            radioButtonNo.TabIndex = 1;
            radioButtonNo.TabStop = true;
            radioButtonNo.Text = "False";
            radioButtonNo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            radioButtonNo.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

            radioButtonYes.AutoSize = true;
            radioButtonYes.TabIndex = 0;
            radioButtonYes.Text = "True";
            radioButtonYes.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            radioButtonYes.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

            panel1.AutoScroll = true;
            panel1.Controls.Add(testControl1);
            panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            panel1.Name = "panel1";
            panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(560, 219);
            panel1.TabIndex = 1;

            AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(560, 219);
            Controls.Add(panel1);
            Name = "Form3";
            Text = "Form3";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel is trying to keep focusable controls within view for the user.  To change that, you would have to use your own panel:

```
public class PanelEx : Panel {
  protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl) {
    return this.DisplayRectangle.Location;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works! But why doesn't TabPage keep focused Items within view?

Comment: @oliver Not sure.  I would have to look at the source code, but I'm guessing a TabPage doesn't call ScrollToControl or the ScrollControlIntoView code.

Comment: One additional comment: DisplayRectangle.Location seems to take Panel.Padding into account (found this out while single-stepping through the call to DisplayRectangle), which leads to slightly odd behavior when the scrollbars have already been displaced while resizing (the view always "drifts" to the top left corner, no matter if resize grows larger or smaller, or even if you just wiggle at the resize handle). If the intended behavior is really to keep the view where it has been during resizing (even if Padding is non-zero), you would have to return AutoScrollPosition instead.